# Pandas adding calculated vectors into df

Tags: python, pandas, vector

my goal is to add formula based vectors to my following df:

```
Day Name a b 1 2 x1 x2  
1   ijk  1 2 3 3  0 1
2   mno  2 1 1 3  1 1
```

outcome:

```
Day Name a b 1 2 x1 x2  y1      y2     z1                z2  
1   ijk  1 2 3 3  0 1 (1*2)+3 (1*2)+3 (1+2)*(3*1+0*1)  (1+2)*(3*2+1*2)
2   mno  2 1 1 3  1 1 (2*1)+1 (2*1)+3 (2+1)*(1*1+1*1)  (2+1)*(3*2+1*2)
```

This is my tedious approach:

```
df[y1] = df[a]*df[b]+df[1]  #This is y1 = a*b+value of column 1
df[y2] = df[a]*df[b]+df[2]  #This is y2 = a*b+value of column 2
```

if column 3 and x3 were added in then: y3 would be y3 = a*b+value of column 3,

if column 4 and x4 were added in then: y4 = a*b+value of column 4 and so on...

```
df[z1] = (df[a]+df[b])*(df[1]*1+df[x1]*1) The "1" here is from the column name 1 and x1  #z1 = (a+b)*[(value of column 1)*1+(value of column x1)*1]
df[z2] = (df[a]+df[b])*(df[1]*2+df[x1]*2) The "2" here is from the column name 2 and x2  #z2 = (a+b)*[(value of column 2)*2+(value of column x2)*2]
```

if column 3 and x3 were added in then: z3 = (a+b)*[(value of column 3)*3+(value of column x3)*3] and so on

This works fine; however, this will get tedious if there are more columns added in.  For example, it might get "3 4,... x3 x4,..." I'm wondering if there's a better approach to this using a loop maybe?

Many thanks :)

Comment: Is there a pattern to your new variables?

Comment: @Dan Yes, they're just 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... and x1 x2 x3 x4 ....

Comment: I meant to the formulae

Comment: @Dan I updated the formula.  Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'ijk', 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 1],
                   [2, 'mno', 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1]],
                  columns=['Day', 'Name', 'a', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 'x1', 'x2'])

for i in range(1, 4):
    df['y'+str(i)] = df['a'] * df['b'] + df[i]

#output
#Day    Name    a   b   1   2   3   x1  x2  y1  y2  y3
#1     ijk      1   2   3   3   2   0   1   5   5   4
#2     mno      2   1   1   3   1   1   1   3   5   3
```